# '\U' used without hex digits in character string (<input>:4:36) when starting r" error when starting r

Tags: r, error-handling

I just re-downloaded r. And for some reason no matter how many time I try or in what folder I put it or what version I use when r is starting it gives me this error '\U' used without hex digits in character string (:4:36) when starting r

[image]

Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: Delete the `.rdata` file for earlier session. If you ae a Windows or MacOS user you may first need to use your system file manager to make these visible.

Comment: Check your `.Rprofile` for something that contains `C:\Users\you\...`, those need to be double-backslashes as in `C:\\Users\\you\\...`.